# how to make scrollbar able to scroll to change the language

Tags: android, keyboard

I have developed a custom keyboard for android, but I don't know how to make the space bar able to scroll to change the language.  I have added a button for that but I didn't like it, is there anyone can help me to know how to make the space bar scroll to change the language?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code that shows what you tried and that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9qBZ.jpg)

I think he/she meant the he did it like this, sorry I dont know the answer but I wanted to explain to EFrank since he posted a comment to see your try but your question said that you dont know how to do it so you did a walk around.

Hope you got an answer on your question.
Best Regards,